# Making a lightbox inside a box

Tags: jquery, image, web, lightbox

I make a website wich has this included:
http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/1191/Awesome-jQuery-and-CSS3-Interactive-menu

so check it out for a minute to see what it does, now what i like to have is when you click for example on 1 it opens a box. In that box i want to store 3 or more images (no problems so far) but i want to be able to click on these images and make a lightbox like this one: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/925/Lightbox-v2.05-Support-IE9-with-jQuery

now i tried a few things but haven't really got it working, is there any one who can help me make this work? if you want me to share my code let me now, i only have the code (of the first link in this document) right now working.

I Quickly put the codes into each other to show where it goes wrong, so the problem is it doesnt open the box any more if you click on 1,2,3 etc... (the light box works, i clicked on a few places of the menu and it opens the light box if i clicked under the text: `one`

here is the code i have so far:

**HTML**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>  
        <title>Interactive menu with CSS3 & jQuery</title>

        <!--- Interactive Menu --->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">    
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

        <!--- Light box -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style>
            /* Demo page only */

            #about{
                color: #999;
                text-align: center;
                font: 0.9em Arial, Helvetica;
            }

            #about a{
                color: #777;
            }       
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

      <ul class="menu">
        <li tabindex="1">
          <span class="title">One</span> 
          <div class="content"><div class="thumbnail">
            <a title="Roll over and click right side of image to move forward." rel="lightbox[plants]" href="images/image-3.jpg"><img height="40" width="100" alt="Plants: image 1 0f 4 thumb" src="images/thumb-3.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a title="Alternately you can press the right arrow key." rel="lightbox[plants]" href="images/image-4.jpg"><img height="40" width="100" alt="Plants: image 2 0f 4 thumb" src="images/thumb-4.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a title="The script preloads the next image in the set as you're viewing." rel="lightbox[plants]" href="images/image-5.jpg"><img height="40" width="100" alt="Plants: image 3 0f 4 thumb" src="images/thumb-5.jpg"></a>
        </div></div>
        </li>

        <!---- The other Menu's --->
        <li tabindex="1">
          <span class="title">Two</span> 
          <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.</div>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="1">
          <span class="title">Three</span> 
          <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.</div>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="1">
          <span class="title">Four</span> 
          <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.</div>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="1">
          <span class="title">Five</span> 
          <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.</div>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="1">
          <span class="title">Six</span> 
          <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.</div>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="1"> 
          <span class="title">Seven</span>
          <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.</div>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="1"> 
          <span class="title">Eight</span>
          <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.</div>
        </li>
        <li tabindex="1"> 
          <span class="title">Nine</span>
          <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse interdum dictum scelerisque. Morbi eu euismod lorem.</div>
        </li>     
      </ul>


        <script>
          (function(){

            // Append a close trigger for each block
            $('.menu .content').append('<span class="close">x</span>');     
            // Show window
            function showContent(elem){
                hideContent();
                elem.find('.content').addClass('expanded');
                elem.addClass('cover'); 
            }
            // Reset all
            function hideContent(){
                $('.menu .content').removeClass('expanded');
                $('.menu li').removeClass('cover');     
            }

            // When a li is clicked, show its content window and position it above all
            $('.menu li').click(function() {
                showContent($(this));
            });     
            // When tabbing, show its content window using ENTER key
            $('.menu li').keypress(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
                    showContent($(this));
                }
            });

            // When right upper close element is clicked  - reset all
            $('.menu .close').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                hideContent();
            });     
            // Also, when ESC key is pressed - reset all
            $(document).keyup(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
                  hideContent();
                }
            });

          })();
        </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu{
  width: 620px;
  margin: 100px auto; padding: 15px;      
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: li;
  background: #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.menu:after {
  clear: both;
}

.menu {
  zoom:1;
}

/* -------------------------------- */        

.menu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 120px; width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
} 

.menu li:hover, .menu li:focus{
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(255,255,255,.2)), to(rgba(255,255,255,0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.2), rgba(255,255,255,0));
}

.menu .cover{
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu .cover:focus{
  outline: 0;
}

/* -------------------------------- */

.menu li::after{
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  font: italic bold 10px serif, georgia;
  position: absolute;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-out; 
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;  
  transition: all .2s ease-out;    
}      

.menu li:hover::after, .menu li:focus::after{
  font-size: 100px;
  opacity: 1; 
}

.menu .cover::after{
  z-index: -1;
}

/* -------------------------------- */       

.menu li:nth-child(1),
.menu li:nth-child(2),
.menu li:nth-child(3){
  margin-top: 0;
}

.menu li:nth-child(1),
.menu li:nth-child(4),
.menu li:nth-child(7){
  margin-left: 0;      
}

/* -------------------------------- */       

.menu li:nth-child(1),
.menu li:nth-child(1) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(1) .close{
  background-color: #2c618f;
}         

.menu li:nth-child(2),
.menu li:nth-child(2) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(2) .close{
  background-color: #91ab31;   
}   

.menu li:nth-child(3),
.menu li:nth-child(3) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(3) .close{
  background-color: #714a28;   
}

.menu li:nth-child(4),
.menu li:nth-child(4) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(4) .close{
  background-color: #e58600;      
}

.menu li:nth-child(5),
.menu li:nth-child(5) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(5) .close{
  background-color: #c33a00;
}

.menu li:nth-child(6),
.menu li:nth-child(6) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(6) .close{
  background-color: #7f5dac;
}

.menu li:nth-child(7),
.menu li:nth-child(7) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(7) .close{
  background-color: #5672b7;     
}

.menu li:nth-child(8),
.menu li:nth-child(8) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(8) .close{
  background-color: #69003f;
}

.menu li:nth-child(9),
.menu li:nth-child(9) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(9) .close{
  background-color: #393043;
}

/* -------------------------------- */

.menu .content{
  opacity: 0; display: none\9;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica;
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px; width: 200px; /* Ideally: height: 100%; width: 100%; but works at it should just in FF */
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out; 
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;  
  transition: all .3s ease-out;      
}  

.menu .expanded{
  opacity: .95; display: block\9;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 40px;
  height: 300px; width: 540px; /* Cover the entire area */
}

.menu li:nth-child(3n) .content{ /* 3,6,9 */
  right: 0;
}

.menu li:nth-child(3n-1) .expanded{ /* 2,5,8 */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -310px;
}

.menu li:nth-child(7) .content, /* 7,8,9 */
.menu li:nth-child(8) .content,
.menu li:nth-child(9) .content{
  bottom: 0;
}                      

.menu li:nth-child(4) .expanded, /* 4,5,6 */
.menu li:nth-child(5) .expanded,
.menu li:nth-child(6) .expanded{
  margin-top: -190px;
  top: 50%;
} 

/* -------------------------------- */    

.menu .title{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font: italic bold 1em/120px 'trebuchet MS', Arial, helvetica;
  opacity: .2;
}

.menu li:hover .title{
  opacity: .7;
}    

/* -------------------------------- */

.menu .close {
  display: none;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px; width: 40px;
  font: bold 20px/40px arial, helvetica;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: -20px; right: -20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;      
}

.menu .cover .close{
  display: block;
}
```

Not sure if i can show you the show the Jquery and Javascript code but i just used the standard code of the 2 links so i changed nothing about that.

Comment: please share your latest code you have tried and which is not working!

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui i will put my code here, i try to make it as short as i can.give me a few minutes